# Simultaneous UIViewController Transition Animations

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am trying to fade-in a background gradient image and slide up a `uiview` card from the bottom (off-screen) to the center of the `uiviewcontroller` - executing both animations simultaneously when the `uiviewcontroller` is presented modally.

What I've attempted is to set the `uiviewcontroller` modal transition style to cross dissolve, which would provide the fade-in effect for the background gradient image, and in `viewDidAppear` run the animation to slide up the `uiview` card from the bottom to center.

While this works, there's a slight delay with the card, and ideally I hoped both animations took place at the same time.

Is this grouping possible? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Below is relevant code in the modally presented view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    alertViewCenterYConstraint.constant += view.bounds.height

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.alertViewCenterYConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works like a magic.  I love it.

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    alertViewCenterYConstraint.constant += view.bounds.height
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.05, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.alertViewCenterYConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly! is it due to running the animation on the main thread? just curious.

Comment: Yes. You are right. If not on the main thread, it blocks the layout. If you try, you can see it.